# Service object reusable?

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm using the Python Google Drive SDK with a service account app and I want to try to cache the service object in some way to minimize web requests when building it.

```
    service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)
```

If I reuse this object and possibly in multiple threads will this cause problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Httplib2 objects are not thread safe](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/thread_safety). However, you should have no issue reusing the service, just make sure you're [getting a new access token after an hour](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#expiration).

Answer (score 0):

Client and service objects keep state info, therefore the client is not thread-safe. One obvious example is token is being kept immutably and being refreshed on authorization errors that leads to a racing condition.

Comment: So because this is a service account app, the credentials are always the same using SignedJwtAssertionCredentials.  It sounds like there may still be some state info that is not thread safe?